# How to work on multiple browsers within a single testcase in TestRigor?

Tags: testrigor

I need to invoke a new (other) browser within a testcase.
Say., If we are working by default on Chrome, I need to invoke a Firefox/Edge browser within the testcase. Additionally the user session in one browser is expected to be retained when we switch across the two browsers. How is this achievable with TestRigor?

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on your Test Suite.
2. Click 'Settings' at the bottom of the left hand column
3. Click the 'Multiple browsers' tab at the top of the page.
4. Choose the OS (Windows, Ubuntu (Linux) or OSX (Mac)
5. Choose the Browser for the chosen system.
6. Click the 'Add Browser' button.
7. Click the 'Save' button

Return to a test.
Under 'Quick Actions' click 'Re-test'
Click the Execution UUID link and you can see all OS/Browser combinations executing.

[image: testRigor executing under multiple OS / Browsers]